# Is there a better way to update existed field index after mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set `dynamic` to `false` to disable dynamic mapping. But I forgot to add a field to mapping. I added the field after indexing all the documents, so Elasticsearch won't index the existed field in the documents.

The original mapping

```sh
{
  "customers" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the documents are like

```sh
"_source" : {
  "name" : "Bob"
  "favourite" : "cake"
}
```

The field `favourite` was added to mapping after indexing the document.

I have to update all the documents to index the existed field, is there a better way?

Comment: Current workaround is to use `_reindex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previously indexed documents will not change and notice about your new update so if you want all of your documents to have the same properties on their fields, I guess the only way is to reindex your current index to the new index with your desired mapping and use reindex API.

```html
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "oldindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  }
}
```